# A bit confused as to why my loop is not ending

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, do-while

So here is my code:

```
int k = 1;
string sTemp = "";

do {
    cout << "Enter the ID number for sequence " << k << ": ";
    cin >> sTemp;
    if(!bValid_digit(sTemp))
        cout << "Invalid input. ID number must be 3 digits long.\n\n";
    else if(bIs_taken(sTemp))
        cout << "Invalid input. ID number cannot be the same as a previous member.\n\n";
    else {
        k++;
        ID.push_back(sTemp);
        stored_ID.push_back(sTemp);
    }
}
while(bIs_taken(sTemp) || !bValid_digit(sTemp) || ID.size() != 10);
```

What I'm doing there is getting user input for a 3-digit ID member, for which I have a separate function `bValid_digit()`, which works fine; then I test if the ID number is already taken by using the function `bIs_taken()`, which also works fine; then I test for `ID.size() != 10` in the condition of the do-while loop, because I only want the user to input 10 ID numbers, and therein lies the problem. Why is the loop not exiting when `ID.size()` reaches 10?

I tested the `ID.size()` by `cout`ing the size after each run of the loop and it does indeed reach size 10 after the 10th valid ID input, but the loop still doesn't end. Why?

Edit: `ID` and `stored_ID` are both string vectors somewhere else in the function.

Comment: It's generally bad form to link to code, rather than including it in your question.  Also, it'd help if you tagged with the language (C++?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reevaluate `bIs_taken(sTemp)` multiple times:

1. it evaluates to false in the if test because you haven't pushed the ID yet
2. but it evaluates to true in the while condition because you've just added the value

Either

- store the first returned value and use it in the condition
- or simplify your loop condition to `while (ID.size() != 10)` , the other two being redundant (you can't reach the tenth if the length is invalid or the id is already taken)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is ID.size() != 10 because it only looks for that value what happens if its 11 it will still run.

Change that to   ID.size() < 10, with the above != that will not work in the loop..

Comment: @Joe Z... True, but you know what I was trying to say.. We gave almost identical answers :)... Nice pick!

Comment: Yep!  We sure did!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify that entire condition down to:

```
while(ID.size() < 10);
```

Since you only push items onto ID when they're valid, there's no reason to repeat the validity tests in the `while()` condition.

Comment: Changed it to ID.size() < 10 but still getting the same problem: http://i.imgur.com/o0Hv6tM.png

Comment: Not sure what to tell you.  Try printing out `ID.size()` and see if it's doing what you think it ought to be doing.

Comment: I just added a break when ID.size() == 10. I shouldn't have to but whatever. Thanks anyway